# Check if user has changed the device passcode in Swift or Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, fingerprint, touch-id

I'm wondering if there's a way to check if a user has changed the device passcode since the last time he oppenend my app.
I know it's possible to get this information with fingerprints (added or removed fingerprints) with something like this:

```
let context = LAContext()
context.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)

if let domainState = context.evaluatedPolicyDomainState
    where domainState == oldDomainState  {
    // Enrollment state the same

} else {
    // Enrollment state changed

}
```

but I would like to know if it's possible just with the device passcode.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to know (i.e. what problem are you trying to solve)?

Comment: @i_am_jorf I'm asked to add extra security to my app, so this is one requirement. When the user adds/removes a fingerprint or changes the device passcode, I need to logout the session in oder to ask user to login again. Security stuff....

Comment: Can you check the login credentials when your app comes back to the foreground after the passcode was changed?

Comment: @koen I'm always checking a token. When token expires it will ask user to login. I want to kill the token when user changes password so it will ask again to login